# How to save a PowerPoint presentations's template?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, templates

I downloaded a presentation and I like its template. How can I save the template for my own future use?

Answer (score 3):

To save it, click File -> Save as -> Choose .pot extention in the default Powerpoint template folder.

Comment: Or `.potx` if its a newer version of PowerPoint.

Comment: By ".pot" do you mean PowerPoint Template? Note that I want to save the temple only and not the content of the presentation itself.

Comment: I think you will need to remove the content first and save what you have as the template.

Comment: Dave's correct. If you save a presentation as a template without first deleting the slides in it, when you start a new presentation based on that template, you get the slides too.  That can be useful, if you want the new presentation to start with a selection of pre-made slides.  Otherwise, delete all the slides, or leave just a blank title slide, for example.  When you apply a template to an existing presentation, PPT won't add any slides from the template; you get the design but none of the content.